# Appcelerator Studio - cannot build app with studio

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I'm not quit sure what happend, but since a few days I'm getting following error when trying to build my appc titanium app directly from the appcelerator studio:

```
[ERROR] :  "Resources" directory not found
[ERROR] :  Ensure the "Resources" directory exists and contains an "app.js" file.
```

When I compile it from the commandline it works

```
$ appc alloy compile --config platform=ios && appc ti build -p ios

Appc Version
6.2.4

Appc Ti Version 
5.0.14
```

I need to use this versions since the app is a bit old and it is recommended to build them with that toolchain.
However - everything worked before.

Now I have to rebuild with `alloy` before building.
How can I fix that, so that I'm able to build directly from the studio?

Comment: hi, how did you solve it?